# Multiple SMPP Sessions

Tags: java, smpp

Lets say there are two receiver session from same application to a SMPP over different TCP ports.
Message is sent to application and reply is (i.e deliver_sm_resp) is coming to SMPP via the other session 
Is this possible or reply should be come over the same SMPP session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the deliver_sm_resp should be sent back using the same session as the deliver_sm was received on.

The response is linked with the request by a sequence number that is incremented with each request on the session so the it only makes sense within the same session.