# Multiple SMPP Session on Same Bind (System ID)

Tags: smpp

1. Assuming I have an ESME binding and pushing bulk SMS to an SMSC, what is the advantage of having multiple (say 2 or 3) tcp/ip sessions to the same SMSC (same IP/Port & sys-ID), if the SMSC has specific fixed send window (say total of 200 for the ESME), regardless number of sessions?
2. If upon the implementation above at one instance, session no1 is removed, what happens to the packets that session was expecting to receive from SMSC, would remote SMSC re-route them to other session since ip, port & system ID are same?

I read this too already:
[Multiple SMPP Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909687/multiple-smpp-sessions/48911554?__=1497141205#48911554)

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about multiple bindings from an ESME to an SMSC.Most of the SMSC has implementation to handle multiple bindings from the same Ip and port.SMSC will calculate the total of messages from all the bindings.

**Answer to Number :1**

Multiple  bindings are useful when ESME wants to send more number of messages.For example : If your ESME limit is 100 messages per second in an single TCP Connection and your requirement is 300 messages per second to your SMSC,then you can bind another two connections to the SMSC and send 100 messages per second for each connection,so you can achieve 300 messages per second from your ESME to your SMSC.

**Answer to Number :2**

2.Its based on your SMSC Implementation.But,In most of the cases,the remaining packets will be sent from other connections if available